# Start-Process powershell is not adding result to textbox

Tags: forms, powershell, button, textbox

I'm trying to add command output to textbox.
But it is not doing anything.
What am I missing ?
I tried the command directly in Powershell console and it is working fine, and I can see there the output.
But why it is not displaying the output here in the textbox?

here is my code

```
$showstatussh = {plink admin@192.168.1.1 -pw '' -m E:\PSGTM\statussh.txt}

$button_click = {
$textboxResults.Text = Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "-Command $showstatussh"
}

$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Text = "my control"
$Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,300)
$Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$Form.Topmost = $True

$StatusS = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$StatusS.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(30,150)
$StatusS.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(230,30)
$StatusS.Text = "Show Status"
$StatusS.BackColor = [System.Drawing.ColorTranslator]::FromHtml("#cdafa8")
$StatusS.Add_Click($button_click)

$textboxResults = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textboxResults.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,190)
$textboxResults.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,20)

$Form.Controls.AddRange(($StatusS, $textboxResults))

$form.showdialog()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i figure out the solution

Instead of:

```
$button_click = {
$textboxResults.Text = Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "-Command $showstatussh"
}
```

I did:

```
$button_click = {
$textboxResults.Text = .$showstatussh
}
```